# Vagrant & Nginx - Name Based Virtual Hosts

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant

I believe I have set up an nginx virtual host file correctly, however, I'm not able to navigate to that URL on the host machine. I have a slight feeling that I'm misunderstanding something here.

Here's the situation.
I have a Vagrantfile that does the following:

- Installation of Required Packages
- Composer Update
- Copies an Nginx Virtual Host file over to Nginx
- Restarts all relevant services

Heres the vhost file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vagrant;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I can verify that when the virtual host file was called simply `vagrant` and the server name was set to the following `server_name _;` that a page was rendered when I visited `localhost`.

As I'm trying to set up Magento, which doesn't work well with localhost domains, I'm trying to set up a name based virtual host for it under the domain dev.magento.co.uk

If I ssh into the vagrant installation, I can verify that the dev.magento.co.uk file is in the /etc/nginx/site-enabled directory and that it's contents were copied over correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: is your Vagrant host forwarding port 80 to your VM?

Comment: You own the Magento.co.uk domain? Our have you otherwise configured DNS on the host?

Comment: @Thomas I think Vagrant does this as standard. However, I think I have to use port 8080; dev.magento.co.uk:8080 does not work also.

Comment: @Melvyn It's just a local virtual host, not a published web example. Vagrant install is on my local machine not a webserver.

Comment: A "virtual host" entry in a webserver does not setup DNS for you in the Virtual Machine Host. Connect on Ip using a low level tool like telnet or netcat. Then request the homepage with the correct Host header. If that works, you really need to configure the host name on the VM host.